# matlab: store a vector as a single element in a dataset/table

Tags: matlab, dataset

I would like to build a dataset (or a table, if you think it's better suited) where one of the columns, 'Coefficients', contains a vector of doubles of length, say, 3. Something like this:

```
Variable          Use     Coefficients 
Efficiency        Pred    1.3  1.5  0.7  
PressureRatio     Optim   3.7  0.5  9.7 
Power             Optim   7.0 -1.4 -2.4
```

The point is, usually you would build the dataset like this:

```
Variable          Use     Coeff1 Coeff2 Coeff3
Efficiency        Pred    1.3      1.5     0.7  
PressureRatio     Optim   3.7      0.5     9.7 
Power             Optim   7.0     -1.4    -2.4
```

However, my code must be general enough to accomodate a generic number of coefficients: I don't want to add or delete a new column, each time I decide to try a different number of coefficients. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: so why don't you use a `table` then? `table(ones(10,3),ones(10,1))`

Comment: how does your code look like now? dataset supports arrays. Load the `hospital` dataset  that comes with MATLAB and check the last two columns

Comment: @m.s., Mohsen Nosratinia, thanks a lot! It was way easier than I expected :)